# How to Create A subscription button in Django

Tags: python, django, web

I'm new to web development and Python programming.

I want to create a button where users can subscribe to and unsubscribe from a sub-channel (much like a forum category) in a forum.

What I really want is for a user to be capable of subscribing and unsubscribing by clicking the button of the sub-channel.

views.py:

```py
class SubChannelSubscriptionView(ListView):
    template_name = 'subscription.html'
    model = Topic

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SubChannelSubscription.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SubChannelSubscriptionView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['SubChannel'] = SubChannel.objects.all()
        context['top'] = Topic.objects.filter(category__subchannel_subs__user=self.request.user)
        return context

    def subd(self, request):
        subchannel = get_object_or_404(SubChannel, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        is_subd = False
        if subchannel.subd.filter(pk=request.user).exists():
            subchannel.subd.remove(request.user)
            is_subd = False
        else:
            subchannel.is_subd.add(request.user)
            is_subd = True
        return reverse('index')
```

models.py:

```py
class SubChannel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    subd = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subd' )
```

subscription.html:

```html
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if is_subd %}
        {% for sb in SubChannel %}
            <button type="submit" value="" > subd{{ sb }} </button>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
         {% for sb in SubChannel %}
              <button type="submit"  value="" >not sub {{ sb }}</button>
         {% endfor %}    
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: This would probably work if you renamed your method to `post`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple way to toggle between subscription is to create a url for it and execute it by ajax.
this url, in its view, we get the user and channel, then we can find by querying that if the user is subscribed to channel if True then remove him else add that user to the channel.

I can't post any code for it because I didn't understand the logic. Here I noticing that `SubChannel` have ForaignKey `channel` and ManyToManyField of User.

I think there should be only two Models

1. Channel
2. User -> ManyToManyField Channel

By this one can easily manage user having multiple channels and all users subscribed to a channel. Adding a Third DBTable of UserChannel is done internally by Django ORM. *(I understand that this may not be sutaible for your specific requirements.)*